# Google webapp with UI Services - Run another webapp url in popup window

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, google-apps-script

Somehow I think this should be easy but I cannot find how to do it. I have created a webapp within a Google Drive Spreadsheet. In the webapp I am using Ui services and using it to create popups when buttons are pressed. What I would like to do is when I click on a button I would like to open a popup panel and within it run another webapp by calling the https url and displaying this second webapp within the pop up window of the first.

Does anyone know whether this is possible using UIServices within Apps Script?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Are you considering using PopupPanel?

Comment: Phil,Something like a popup panel. Basically I have a webapp which I want to run another webapp from within displayed in a PopupPanel or similar. Ideally in the popup panel I render a webpage (which happens to be a webapp) by calling its url.